# Vertical align in a div with no space around the h1

Tags: html, css

I have to get my content div vertical centered in my header div, and i also dont need space around the content div because i did have it working but it would take up width 100% everytime. Here is my code

```css
#header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
}
#content {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="content">
    <h1>Jari Rengeling</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just remove float:left; from content div and will vertically align. because float lifts the element from the normal flow of element. may be this link help you for centering div vertically http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure if this is what you are trying to achieve:

https://jsfiddle.net/pf8oujj6/

Use

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display:flex` with `align-items:center` on `#header` .

is this what you are looking for ?

```css
#header
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}

#content
{
   
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
}

h1
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
        <div id="content">
        <h1>Jari Rengeling</h1>
        </div>
</div><!-- #header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove float left in the content.

https://jsfiddle.net/4tc95oy0/

```
#content
{
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Float transform youre element in display block override the previous declaration of display table-cell.